# SQL Server query to display data in the following format--

Tags: sql-server

```
patientno   cardName  cardtype
------------------------------
101         abc123     1001
102         wre234     1002
102         ioi123     1002
102         uio345     1003
103         opt123     1004
103         jhy126     1005
```

Expected output:

```
patientno              cardname 
-------------------------------
101                   1001:abc123
102                   1002:wre234,1002:ioi123,1003:uio345
103                   1004:opt123,1005:jhy126
```

Answer (score 1):

`Group_concat` as in `MySQL` is not available in `SQL Server` up to the current version.

You have some manual options though:

1) build a scalar function that takes an patient name/id as parameter and shows concatenated card name/type values and apply this function to each employee
  2) use xml functions

```
    SELECT patientno, cardName = STUFF((SELECT 
                  cardName + ':' +  cardtype
                  FROM @x AS x2 WHERE patientno= x.patientno
                  ORDER BY row_num
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
    FROM @x AS x
    GROUP BY patientno
    ORDER BY patientno;
```

**NOTE**
Query is not tested may have some syntax error.

You can read more about [Stuff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: IAm getting error when i modified accrding my req -Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 52 Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: Check the line number and show me which line is giving you this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `stored procedure` that contains a loop that retrieves the `patientno` one by one and the related data of `cardName` and `cardType` can be concatenated by using `coalesce` function.

```
Create table #tmp(patientno int, cardName varchar(max));

declare @patientno int;
set @patientno= 0;

declare @cardName varchar(max);

Select @patientno=Min(patientno) From patientTable 
Where patientno > @patientno

WHILE (@patientno is not null AND @patientno > 0) BEGIN
    Select @cardName = coalesce(',', @cardName) + cardtype + ':' + cardName
    from patientTable where patientno = @patientno

    Insert into #tmp(patientno, cardName)Values(@patientno, @cardName);

    --Fetch Next
    Select @patientno=Min(patientno) From patientTable 
    Where patientno > @patientno    
END

Select * From #tmp;
```

This is the logic only. you can modify it as per your requirement to make it work.

Comment: IAm getting error when i modified accrding my req -Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 52
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: what is the datatype of patientno and cardtype?

Comment: the above query returning only one patient with one card num, if the patient is having 3 cardnum's its displaying only the 3rd row details only , its for all patient the same thing happening

Comment: Do you know [COALESCE](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms190349.aspx&ei=suviVIb0II3muQSS14DQDA&usg=AFQjCNHL2NTBIFjyVDUnJiK1pVykVTf0Rw&sig2=co0IPlS9rOt8NRpnB0ymiw&bvm=bv.85970519,d.c2E&cad=rjt) mewthod. it will concatenate your records in a single string with a separator whatever you want. for example `cardName: 1001,1002,1003` for any patient. And I have created a loop that takes each patient's data and inserts the record in a temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a code which will concatenate SQL string ([see this article](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) on my website). This tutorial shows how to concatenate string on SQL Server using FOR XML PATH. Please give a try to the below SELECT statement

```
/*
create table PatientData (patientno int, cardName varchar(25), cardtype int)
go;
insert into PatientData select 101,'abc123',1001
insert into PatientData select 102,'wre234',1002
insert into PatientData select 102,'ioi123',1002
insert into PatientData select 102,'uio345',1003
insert into PatientData select 103,'opt123',1004
insert into PatientData select 103,'jhy126',1005
*/

with patients as (
    select distinct patientno from PatientData
)
select
    p.patientno,
    STUFF(
        (
          SELECT ',' + cast(d.cardtype as varchar(10))+ ':' + d.cardName
          FROM PatientData d
          WHERE d.patientno = p.patientno
          FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
          ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
        ), 1, 1, '') as cardname
from patients p
```

Output will be as follows which you require

```
101 1001:abc123
102 1002:wre234,1002:ioi123,1003:uio345
103 1004:opt123,1005:jhy126
```